# How does instagram do username system without having get ID's like in PHP

Tags: php, instagram

I am building a small social network for college and I want to have the username's appear like this `http://www.example.com/username` like Instagram does it, but what I know is something like this `http://www.example.com/profile?id=username` but I don't want this way **http://www.example.com/profile?id=username** I want it this way **http://www.example.com/username** . Please how do I go about this.

Comment: Instagram likely doesn't use PHP. Supposedly it's written in Python and Django.

Comment: There are a variety of approaches and frameworks which do this.  Terms you're looking for are things like "clean URLs", "pretty URLs", "SEO friendly URLs", "clean query strings", etc.

Comment: do you know what it is a url rewrite and routers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each PHP framework supports [Semantic urls](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantic_URL) (pretty URLs). With the Slim Framework this is very easy to implement:

```
<?php
use \Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface as Request;
use \Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface as Response;

require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

$app = new \Slim\App;
$app->get('/{username}', function (Request $request, Response $response) {
    $username = $request->getAttribute('username');
    $response->getBody()->write("Hello, $username");

    return $response;
});
$app->run();
```

You could start with the [Slim Framework 3 Skeleton Application](https://github.com/slimphp/Slim-Skeleton).